# How to make a column stretch to fill container div (while being responsive)

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (latest version - 2.3.2) for a site I'm building, and want to achieve the following while keeping the site responsive, and also applying best practices for it.

Here's a very rough sketch of what I want to have:

[image: (Extremely basic) Sketch of site]

The site has a basic header with fixed navbar, a content-fluid div which has three inner divs: a span5, span6, and span1 (for a total of 12 columns). After the content div, a sticky footer with company/copyright info and such.

The problem I'm having is with the span1 column. It is basically decorative (it has 4 vertical color bars, sized at 25% width each), but I'd like to have:

- Social link icons vertically-centered in the column (Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, etc), as shown by the black boxes.
- Text rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise inside each colored bar. It's only one word each, and is not a priority.
- Each bar stretching to fill the full height of the parent container (in this case, the content div), since the height of the page is currently set by the highest div, whether it's span5 or span6.

I know there are probably lots of ways to achieve this (pure CSS, javascript, background-image tiling), but I'm looking for the best practices: avoiding extra markup, using right techniques, in order to learn as much as possible. I've tried setting the parent container (and inner bars) to height: 100%; and playing with min-height as well, but min-height doesn't (seem to) work with percentages.

Any help and/or constructive criticism is very welcome.

Edit: JSFiddle and full code added: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9C2nJ/4/)

Also, link to the original site (in case JSFiddle screws something up): [Original page](http://geotelca.com/sitio/contacto.html)

```
<!-- Part 1: Wrap all page content here -->
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                </button> <a class="brand" href="#">Geolog&iacute;a y Telecomunicaciones, C.A.</a>

                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Inicio</a>

                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#acerca-de">Acerca de</a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="decorative-lightblue"></div>
            <div class="decorative-purple"></div>
            <div class="decorative-orange"></div>
            <div class="decorative-lightorange"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Begin page content -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid content clearfix" style="margin-top: 60px;">
            <div class="span5">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span5">
                        <div class="span12 logo"></div>
                        <div class="sidebar-intro">Construcci&oacute;n, Adaptaci&oacute;n,
                            <br/>Adecuaci&oacute;n y Remodelaci&oacute;n
                            <br/>de <span class="emphasis-red">
                                        locales<br>comerciales<br>empresariales
                                    </span>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span7">
                        <!-- Responsive iFrame -->
                        <div class="Flexible-container">
                            <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=8.561755,-71.204721&amp;spn=0.004716,0.006571&amp;t=m&amp;z=18&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
                            <br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/?ie=UTF8&amp;ll=8.561755,-71.204721&amp;spn=0.004716,0.006571&amp;t=m&amp;z=18&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Ver mapa m&aacute;s grande</a></small>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="contact-wrapper well">
                        <form>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputName"><i class="icon-user"></i> Nombre</label>
                                <div class="controls controls-row">
                                    <input type="text" class="span12 input-xlarge " id="inputName" placeholder="Su nombre completo">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><i class="icon-envelope"></i> Correo electr&oacute;nico</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="span12 input-xlarge" id="inputEmail" placeholder="nombre@sudominio.com">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><i class="icon-question-sign"></i> Asunto</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="text" class="span12 input-xlarge" id="inputSubject" placeholder="Asunto de su mensaje">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail"><i class="icon-pencil"></i> Mensaje</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <textarea rows="6" class="span12 input-xlarge" placeholder="Haganos llegar sus comentarios, sugerencias, consultas, etc."></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                                </div>
                                <br class="clear">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                <div class="row-fluid span12">
                    <img class="span9 offset2" src="http://geotelca.com/sitio/assets/img/examples/flyer_back.png">
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="row-fluid span12 address"> <address>
                                    Zona Industrial Los Curos, Calle 1, Edif. Geotelca No. A-8, Mérida, Edo. Mérida
                                </address>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid e-mail">
                        <div class="span4 offset6"> <a href="mailto:direccion@geotelca.com">direccion@geotelca.com</a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span1 social-links">
                <div class="row-fluid vertical-bars">
                    <div class="span3 bar bar-lightblue"></div>
                    <div class="span3 bar bar-purple"></div>
                    <div class="span3 bar bar-orange"></div>
                    <div class="span3 bar bar-lightorange"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid-->
    <div id="push"></div>
</div>
<!--/#wrap-->
<div id="footer">
    <div>
        <div class="decorative-lightblue"></div>
        <div class="decorative-purple"></div>
        <div class="decorative-orange"></div>
        <div class="decorative-lightorange"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="muted credit">Dise&ntilde;ado, codificado y mantenido por <a href="http://twitter.com/kenshin23">@kenshin23</a>

        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like now? Perhaps a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help the situation.

Comment: @user1855126 Added jsfiddle and code to the question.

Comment: @limelights: I tried setting min-height and/or height 100% to the bars, container div (class vertical-bars in the code), and various permutations of that sort. Just shooting arrows, as we say around here. Nothing worked except setting min-height to a pixel value to the bars themselves (class bar), but that would mean setting them for each and every resolution. I don't think that would qualify as a "best practice"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your best bet here would be one of the jQuery plug-in out there to accomplish this ... eqHeight.coffee seems to be pretty well documented:

https://github.com/jsliang/eqHeight.coffee/

As for centering those social links in that vertical space, you'd likely have to use more Javascript to do that. Although, honestly I'd probably put them in a div container with position: fixed; and let them slide up and down that column as the user scrolls.

EDIT: 
Just noticed you added your HTML file ... in the case of the first plug-in I linked to, you would need to add a class (perhaps 'eq-height') to each of the columns whose heights you wanted to match (that first outer span5 and span6 and then all the bar column divs individually). Then on jQuery document ready, use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".content").eqHeight(".eq-height");
});
```

Comment: ... another similar plug-in: https://github.com/filamentgroup/jQuery-Equal-Heights